# How to write code for a two variable algebra question

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code for this and I'm completely lost.  I know the answer but am new to code and don't know my way around.  Can someone point me in the right direction even if its just a similar example.

A cash drawer contains 160 bills, all 10s and 50s. The total value of the 10s and 50s is $1,760.

How many of each type of bill are in the drawer? You can figure this out by trial and error (or by doing algebra with pencil and paper), but try to use loops and conditionals to check a plausible possibilities and stop when you find the correct one.

I've tried to write it out in code but keep getting syntax errors. I tried looking up loops and conditionals on google but im still confused.  I think the range function is what I'm looking for but I don't know how to key it in.  I don't want the answer I just want  resources for finding it.

```
print("Print integers within given start and stop number using range  
(function")  
for x in range (1,160)  
print(x, end=',')
```

Indentation error:  Expected an indented block

Comment: if you need help then show code and full error message.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-make-a-change/

Comment: https://www.algoskills.com/g_coinchange.php

Answer (score 0):

Its has to have loop, i would suggest you use while loops, and have a variable for the dollars and take one down and add one when it doesn't match.
Look up while loops, variables and if statements and you should get it.